# Django doesn't save OneToOne relation assigned before saving

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a `OneToOne` field to itself:

```
class Préinscription(models.Model):
    plus_un = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, default=None, related_name='+')
```

When I try to set this field on an instance, it doesn't work.

In the following code, `pp` and `pp2` are two instances of `Préinscription`.

```
if d['plus_un']:
    pp2.nom = d['nom2']
    pp2.prénom = d['prénom2']
    pp2.mél = d['mél2']
    pp.plus_un = pp2
    pp2.save()
    print(pp2)                 # First print
    p.nb_billets = 2
else:
    pp.plus_un = None
    if pp2.id:
        pp2.delete()
    p.nb_billets = 1

p.save()
print(pp2)                     # Second print
print(pp.plus_un)              # Third print
pp.save()
print(pp.plus_un)              # Final print
```

This code gives no errors. However, here is the sequence returned by the prints:

```
Préinscription object (325)
Préinscription object (325)
Préinscription object (325)
None
```

This means that even though the related object is created and all, it isn't saved.

As you can see, I suspected it might be because of a conflict between the `.plus_un` leading to the parent or the child, and so I set `related_name='+'` to avoid that. It does not change anything though, exactly the same results in either case, after migrating.

Note that it does however work when I do it through the CLI (`./manage.py shell`), with the exact same procedure.

Comment: Have you tried saving `pp2` before assigning it? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) say: "Note that you must save an object before it can be assigned to a foreign key relationship.".

Comment: That's probably it. Feel free to leave that as an answer so I can validate it when I try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning an object as a foreign key, it *must* have been saved to the database.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) state that "you must save an object before it can be assigned to a foreign key relationship".

This is inaccurate as Django does not prevent you from assigning an unsaved object (as of v2.1). But if you do that, the parent will be set to `null` when you save the child object. This happens *even if you have saved the assigned parent object in the meantime*. What is particularly insidious is that upon inspecting the parent of the child object (`related_object.parent`) before saving the child, a valid object (with even a `pk` if the parent has been saved in the meantime) is returned. The foreign key is only set to `None` when trying to save.

If you have a non-null constraint on the foreign key, you at least get an error upon saving. But if you don't have that constraint, you'll never know as Django will silent discard the assigned parent while saving both objects without complaint. The exception to that is when using `create()`; Django then throws a `ValueError` before hitting the database.

So be sure to always save first and assign second.

```
# With create(), the object created is immediately saved to the database.
# If you try to save a related_object with an unsaved parent, you get a 
# ValueError.
parent_object = Parent.objects.create(field1=value1, field2=value2)
related_object = Related.objects.create(field3=value3, parent=parent_object)

# Alterative with explicit saving
parent_object = Parent(field1=value1, field2=value2)
related_object = Related(field3=value3)

# First save, then assign – the assignment fails silently if 
# you do it the other way around.
parent_object.save()
related_object.parent = parent_object
related_object.save()
```

Comment: I had read this in the docs, the reason why I overlooked it is that in another situation I got an error message when I did that kind of stuff. Weird it didn't warn me here, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: It only seems to warn when using `create()`, not `save()`. Probably not intended behaviour.